# Data frame convert and combine rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timeseries data frame from machine, in which the values come as different tags and some tags in diff format.

```
| datetime            | tagid  | value |
|---------------------|--------|-------|
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | BNO_01 | 12849 |
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | BNO_02 | 12597 |
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | BNO_03 | 14390 |
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | MDL_01 | 21328 |
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | MDL_02 | 22304 |
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | SEQ_01 | 12340 |
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | SEQ_02 | 13622 |
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | STA    | 724   |
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | STO    | 735   |
```

1. Convert tag ids BNO_01, BNO_02, BNO_03, MDL_01, MDL_02, SEQ_01, SEQ_02
   using 
   df['tagid'] = df['tagid'].apply(lambda x: chr(round(x / 256)) + chr(x % 256)) but only for above tags row
2. delete rows MDL_01,MDL_02,BNO_01,BNO_02,BNO_03 and merge text as BNO row
3. delete rows SEQ_01,SEQ_02, and merge text as SEQ row

Example:
MDL_01= 21328 --> 'SP', 
MDL_02= 22304 --> 'W '
BNO_01= 12849 --> '21'
BNO_02= 12597 --> '15'
BNO_03= 14390 --> '86'

BNO= 'SPW 211586'

Required dataframe

```
| datetime            | tagid | value      |
|---------------------|-------|------------|
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | BNO   | SPW 211586 |
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | SEQ   | 0456       |
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | STA   | 724        |
| 08-04-2021 11:30:58 | STO   | 735        |
```

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh: its conversion using example df['tagid'] = df['tagid'].apply(lambda x: chr(round(x / 256)) + chr(x % 256)).

Comment: Steps:
Step 1. Divide value by 256 and round (Eg 17992/256 which is 70
Step 2. Do Mod the same value (Eg: =Mod(17992,256) which is 72
Step 3. Find Ascii value equitant to 70, which is F
Step 4. Find Ascii value equitant to 72, which is H
Step 5: Concatenate F& H which is FH

Answer (score 2):

Idea is filter values by [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) first filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), processing rows by `lambda function` with `split`, then sorting and after replace `MDL` to `BNO` aggregate values with `join`, last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with original filtered rows with no match condition by `~` for inverted mask:

Advantage of this solution is non matched values are not changed, so never aggregated if duplicates like 2 times `STA` and also not changed `values` to strings.

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

vals = ['BNO','MDL','SEQ']
mask = df['tagid'].str.startswith(tuple(vals))

df1 = df[mask].copy()
df1['value'] = df1['value'].apply(lambda x: chr(round(x / 256)) + chr(x % 256))
df1['tagid'] = df1['tagid'].str.split('_').str[0]

df1 = (df1.sort_values('tagid', ascending=False)
          .replace({'MDL':'BNO'})
          .groupby(['datetime','tagid'])['value']
          .agg(''.join)
          .reset_index())


df = pd.concat([df1, df[~mask]], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
             datetime tagid       value
0 2021-08-04 11:30:58   BNO  SPW 211586
1 2021-08-04 11:30:58   SEQ        0456
2 2021-08-04 11:30:58   STA         724
3 2021-08-04 11:30:58   STO         735
```

Comment: @jexrael: AttributeError: 'PandasArray' object has no attribute '_str_startswith'.

Comment: @user_v27 - What is your pandas version?

Comment: @user_v27 - Maybe need `df['tagid'] = df['tagid'].astype(str)` before my solution.

Comment: pandas 1.1.5. df['tagid'] = df['tagid'].astype(str)- it dosent work

Comment: @user_v27 - What is `print (df['tagid'].dtype)` ?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 80336 entries, 0 to 80335
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------    --------------  -----         
 0   tagid     80336 non-null  object        
 1   value     80336 non-null  object        
 2   datetime  80336 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 3   quality   80336 non-null  int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 2.5+ MB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231056/discussion-between-user-v27-and-jezrael).

Comment: I updated pandas & reinstalled conda. i get the result but in some rows 'value' is W FH102217 and in other FHW 311770. FHW 31177 is correct.

Comment: @user_v27 - Can you check data sample with problemtic data, which not working well?

Comment: @user_v27 Super, is possible post data to question for see how my solution failed if run  problematic data?

Comment: @user_v27 - super, so all rows failed which are in share data?

Comment: @jesrael:complete initial data and result data. in 2 tabs. mixup come in BNO row. Where MDL1&2 gets mixedup random.

Comment: @user_v27 - So maybe not understand, I ask for data which failed. So for simplicity and easy verify is possible remove rows which workinjg correctly?

Comment: @jesrael: https://sharefast.me/AK. Example: in error.csv the value which start with W FH102217 is error. FHW 102217 is ok

Comment: @user_v27 - Sorry, I am lost. Which rows are correct and which not? Can you share correct data? Or how is possible verify what rows failed and what is expected good ouput?

Comment: https://sharefast.me/BA. initial.csv has source file, error2.xlsx marked in orange which has error cells

Answer (score 2):

First change the `value` column values whose `tagid` column contains `_` to char.

Then remove `_` from `tagid` column.

```py
df['value'].update(df.loc[df['tagid'].str.contains('_'), 'value'].apply(lambda x: chr(round(x / 256)) + chr(x % 256)))
df['tagid'] = df['tagid'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
```

```
# print(df)

              datetime tagid value
0  08-04-2021 11:30:58   BNO    21
1  08-04-2021 11:30:58   BNO    15
2  08-04-2021 11:30:58   BNO    86
3  08-04-2021 11:30:58   MDL    SP
4  08-04-2021 11:30:58   MDL    W 
5  08-04-2021 11:30:58   SEQ    04
6  08-04-2021 11:30:58   SEQ    56
7  08-04-2021 11:30:58   STA   724
8  08-04-2021 11:30:58   STO   735
```

Moreover, `groupby()` `datetime` and `tagid` column, and join `value` column in each group with `''`.

```py
df_ = df.groupby(['datetime','tagid']).apply(lambda x: ''.join(map(str, x['value'].tolist()))).reset_index().rename({0: 'value'}, axis=1)
```

```
print(df_)

              datetime tagid   value
0  08-04-2021 11:30:58   BNO  211586
1  08-04-2021 11:30:58   MDL    SPW 
2  08-04-2021 11:30:58   SEQ    0456
3  08-04-2021 11:30:58   STA     724
4  08-04-2021 11:30:58   STO     735
```

At last combine `BNO` and `MDL` row and remove `MDL` row.

```py
df_.loc[df_['tagid'] == 'BNO', 'value'] = df_.loc[df_['tagid'] == 'MDL', 'value'].iloc[0] + ' ' + df_.loc[df_['tagid'] == 'BNO', 'value'].iloc[0]
df_ = df_[~(df_['tagid'] == 'MDL')]
```

```
# print(df_)

              datetime tagid        value
0  08-04-2021 11:30:58   BNO  SPW  211586
2  08-04-2021 11:30:58   SEQ         0456
3  08-04-2021 11:30:58   STA          724
4  08-04-2021 11:30:58   STO          735
```

Comment: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds, in this line df_.loc[df_['tagid'] == 'BNO', 'value'] = df_.loc[df_['tagid'] == 'MDL', 'value'].iloc[0] + ' ' + df_.loc[df_['tagid'] == 'BNO', 'value'].iloc[0]

Comment: @user_v27 What's the output of `print(df_.loc[df_['tagid'] == 'MDL', 'value'])` and `df_.loc[df_['tagid'] == 'BNO', 'value']`.

Comment: Hi i get this error: nothing to repeat at position 0, when i execute df['value'].update(df.loc[df['tagid'].str.contains('_'), 'value'].apply(lambda x: chr(round(x / 256)) + chr(x % 256)))

Comment: @user_v27 Couldn't reproduce unless example data.

Comment: @user_v27 It has no problem with me.

Comment: the below code dint given any error?  hmm. for me it says error: nothing to repeat at position 0, when i execute.  df['value'].update(df.loc[df['tagid'].str.contains('_'), 'value'].apply(lambda x: chr(round(x / 256)) + chr(x % 256)))

Comment: @user_v27 Yeah, it works fine with me. Can you separate those chained function into multiple to find which part gives the error?

Comment: anyways thanks.Im now trying to do pivot of df (tag id), then mod function for those columns necessary and then merge columns. i tried sample it works. so on working further.

Comment: I completed it as per the above comment. Thanks!

Comment: @user_v27 Configurations on your success!